# Idiomatic way to choose the first Some() Option?

Tags: rust, option-type

If I have a number of `Option<T>`'s and I want to pick the first one that is `Some` rather than `None` - is there an idiomatic way to do that?

My naive approach:

```
pub fn pick_first_option_available<T>(a: Option<T>, b: Option<T>, c: Option<T>) -> Option<T> {
    match a {
        Some(a) => Some(a),
        None => match b {
            Some(b) => Some(b),
            None => match c {
                Some(c) => Some(c),
                None => None,
            },
        },
    }
}
```

One obvious issue with the above is that it's limited to a fixed number of Options (3). I would prefer to have a more general function.

There is a somewhat related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779562/is-there-any-built-in-way-to-combine-two-options), but it tackles summing instead of picking options.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there's a simple and idiomatic way:

```
a.or(b).or(c)
```

You don't usually define a function just for this.

[Option#or](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or)

Comment: Wow so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @DenysSeguret answer and you could even abstract it for a generic number of options:

```rust
use std::array;


pub fn pick_first_option_available<T, const N: usize>(options: [Option<T>; N]) -> Option<T> {
    array::IntoIter::new(options).reduce(Option::or).flatten()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=08592e9455454aef3d8067c085aa96cb)

Also, looks like **unpopular** but still a way of doing it other than `Option::or` with a simple loop:

```rust
use std::array;

pub fn pick_first_option_available<T>(a: Option<T>, b: Option<T>, c: Option<T>) -> Option<T> {
    for option in array::IntoIter::new([a, b, c]){
        if option.is_some() {
            return option;
        }
    }
    None
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=85943002b56c528245cd0dc90b30aa35)

Comment: I wonder if the first variant will implement the short-circuiting one (presumably) wants. Maybe something along the lines of `iter.skip_while(Option::is_none).map(Option::unwrap).next()` would have the same effect, and stop iterating at first Some. If you don't like the unwrap, you could use `scan`: `iter.scan(true, |proceed, opt| proceed.then(|| { *proceed = false; opt })).flatten().next()` but that is getting quite obscure.

Comment: Definitely not short circuiting @user4815162342. It may be solved as you say.